# What is Fairy Vearth?

Tags: one-piece

The 'Fairy Vearth' that God Enel keeps talking about, the continuous land.
Is he talking about the moon?

Comment: Please don't ask different unrelated questions in one post. If you wish to ask a separate, unrelated question, please ask it in another question.

Comment: I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: enter image description here!]

> Short-term concentrated [cover series no. 9](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel%27s_mini-series) "To the Fairy Vearth"

Fairy Vearth is a legendary land that Enel mentions throughout the Skypiea Arc. Enel wanted to travel to Fairy Vearth after he destroyed Skypiea. For this purpose he built his ship, Maxim.

After being defeated by Luffy, Enel headed off to Fairy Vearth, which turns out to be the [Moon](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Moon). There he found a group of alien like creatures - who have wings similar to the Skypieans - which Enel befriended.

[Source](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Vearth#Fairy_Vearth)

Answer (score 1):

Fairy Vearth refers to the **Endless Earth**. In de [Enel's mini series](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Enel%27s_mini-series) (*chapter 428-474*) you can read his story. It's a reference for **the moon** where he wanted to travel with his specially build ship **Maxim**.

As for [Montblanc Noland](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Montblanc_Noland), despite the fact that he is known as the world's largest trickster and liar, he was also a very skilled sea man. At the point he was stronger than Zoro and Wiper by a lot at that time.

Comment: I removed the link, because linking to illegal hosting sites is not allowed here (see [this meta post](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/635/6166))

Comment: My bad, wasn't aware of that post, thanks for removing it :3